# JScrollPane doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I made a program and I want to add a JScrollPane to a JTextArea (but it doesn't show up).
Here's the code (or at least everything that has to deal with the JTextArea / JScrollPane, the whole code is a lot):

```
    static JPanel contentPane; // This one got initialised in the constructor
    static JTextArea tarMessages;

    public void addTextArea{
        tarMessages = new JTextArea();
        tarMessages.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        tarMessages.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        tarMessages.setEditable(false);
        tarMessages.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        tarMessages.setBounds(600, 124, 200, 192);
        tarMessages.setOpaque(false);
        /*DefaultCaret dlcMessages = (DefaultCaret)tarMessages.getCaret();
        dlcMessages.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);*/
        tarMessages.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                requestFocus();
            }
        });
        JScrollPane scpMessages = new JScrollPane(tarMessages);
        scpMessages.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scpMessages.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scpMessages.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 192));
        scpMessages.setEnabled(true);
        contentPane.add(scpMessages);
        contentPane.add(tarMessages);
    }
```

Thank you for helping. Have nice holidays.

Comment: `tarMessages.addMouseListener( .. requestFocus() ..` That seems pointless. The default behavior if the user clicks an editable field is to *give it" the input focus.

Comment: A JScrollPane has to be placed in the CENTER of a JPanel with a BorderLayout, or else it won't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    JScrollPane scpMessages = new JScrollPane(tarMessages);
    ...
    contentPane.add(scpMessages);
    contentPane.add(tarMessages);
```

A Swing component can only have a single parent.

First you add the text area to the scroll pane, which is correct.

But then you remove it from the scroll pane when you add it to the content pane.

Get rid of:

```
    ///contentPane.add(tarMessages);
```

Also, when you create the text area use code like:

```
tarMessages = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

This will specify the rows/columns of the text area so it can size itself appropriately.

Don't use setBounds(...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did what you said but now the text area doesn't show up.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I just started and found my mistake. I'll post what I did wrong in an answer to my post so I can tick it and people know that the problem has been solved (the problem was `tarMessages.setBounds(600, 124, ..., ...)`. The result was the text area will be set to a position in the JScrollPane which isn't covered by the pane).

Comment: @Mika *the problem has been solved* - right so you "accept" the answer that provided the solution, which is the answer I provided. *The result was the text area will be set to a position in the JScrollPane* - that is not true. The scroll pane has its own layout manager and will set the bounds of the text area. Your setBounds() statement will be ignored.